# Forcing figures after references

Tags: floats

I'm writing a paper with references and several figures. I'm wondering if it is possible to force some figures at the end of the paper, after the references.
Thanks, Valerio

Comment: Yes, it should be possible: just write the code loading them after the call to references.

Comment: Yep, it works! I erroneously thought that bibliography command had to be the last one.